# Background not working

Tags: html, css

I have a particular css code. But it is not working as expected. I want to cover the whitewrapper div the entire contents. but its not working. I am just getting a div on top and below it my contents are shown. Actually all my contents should be shown inside my whitewrapper.

```
<div id ="Wrapper1">
        <div class ="whitewrapper">
                <div class ="content">
                        <div class ="subleft">
                                loremipsum
                        </div>
                        <div class ="subright">
                                loremipsum
                        </div>
                </div>  
        </div>
</div>
```

```
#Wrapper1{
    float: left;
    margin: 100px 5px 0 95px;
    min-height: 360px;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    width: 900px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
}       
.whitewrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.subleft {
    float: left;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
.subright {
    float: right;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.content{
        width:880px;
        max-width:880px;
}
```

Whats the error?

Comment: `.white_wrapper {background:#000;}` - Classic example of why you should avoid presentational class names.

Comment: I tried it with all color combinations. Even with following code[code].white_wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}[/code] but its not working. Is it the reason for down voting?

Comment: You're being downvoted because it's unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.content {
overflow: auto;
}
```

you should google a bit "css clear float" to understand that

Comment: I tried that too. Its not working as expected. see my comment to Jivings

Answer (score 2):

`.white_wrapper` should be `.whitewrapper`

Comment: edited the typo. but that wont fix my problem. You can test it yourself. actually the whitewrapper should cover the entire text inside the left and right divs. but it is not doing that.

Comment: You mean [White-rapper](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rog8ou-ZepE&ob=av2e)?

Comment: @Madmartigan : I want My contents should to shown inside the whitewrapper. but it is not showing

Comment: Adding a height and removing the float works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qXuGX/1/

Comment: @Jivings : I cant add a fixed height. The height needs to be automatic depending on the content length.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're floating all the content inside the content division. Floated content does not take up any space (vertically) in terms of its parent, because it's essentially removed from the content. Your best solution would be to actually *add* content in between the two floated elements, or set a height on the content division (unreliable).

Alternatively, there is a CSS hack for this, but you'd have to worry about browser compatibility:

```
.whitewrapper:after {
     content: " ";
     display: block;
     clear: both;  
}
```

[See it live.](http://jsfiddle.net/9dKVP/)

---

A better way to stylize the elements would be to make the content container display as a table and its children display as table cells, assuming these will be the only two columns in the layout:

```
.subleft {
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
.subright {
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.content{
    display: table;
    width:880px;
    max-width:880px;
}
```

[See it live.](http://jsfiddle.net/P4fJN/)

Comment: This is a hack for his dodgy css. Wouldn't a better answer teach him how to style it properly?

Comment: @animuson : instead of usinf float, how can I align contents to left and right? So is there a better way than float?

Comment: @user632347: See my update which uses table displays instead of floating.

Comment: @animuson : thanks for teaching me a new info. What if I have sub left and right inside the content div?

Comment: @user632347: I don't understand what you mean; isn't that what you already have?

Comment: @animuson : sorry I mean like this Wrapper > whitewrapper > content > sub_left > sub_sub_left and sub_sub_right.

Comment: @user632347: It would make more sense to just add another table-cell to the main content division so you'd have three columns instead of two.